# jgGrid: How to do a soft refresh on the formatter

Tags: jqgrid, refresh, formatter

I have a jqgrid with a custom formatter that provides some html that changes based on factors unrelated to the underlying [local] table data.

When i sort or filter, the formatter runs and the cell is updated, but my question is :  How can I run this refresh programatically without any user interaction ?

I know that reloadGrid can accomplish this, but it's overkill for what i want because the underlying data really hasn't changed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

reloadGrid ended up being a good solution.  I was just confused because the default "refresh" button also clears search filters.   My solution was to remove the default refresh button and create my own:

```
 jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{search:false,refresh:false,edit:false,add:false,del:false});
    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', "#pager", {
            caption: "", title: "Reload Grid", buttonicon: "ui-icon-refresh",
            onClickButton: function () {
                    $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
            }
    });
```